# Проблема с циклом for

Tags: java

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему во вложенном цикле for при вводе accept2 любого значение кроме Да и Нет не выполняются написанные мной условия, а выполняется цикл по новой? И почему когда я ввожу в accept2 Нет, то у меня просит ввести ответ ещё раз?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[100];
    System.out.print("Введите номер ячейки: ");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next());
    }
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите значение, которое будет хранить ячейка: ");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next());
    }
    int input2 = scan.nextInt();
    array[input] = input2;
    if (input >= 0 && input <= 100) {
        System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + input + " теперь содержит значение " + input2);
    } else if (input >= 100 || input < 0) {
        System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю, введите число от 0 до 100");
    }

    System.out.println("Хотите проверить, чему равна любая ячейка массива?");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        String accept = scan.next();
        if (accept.equals("Да") || accept.equals("да") || accept.equals("дА")) {
            for (int itwo = 0; itwo < 10; itwo++) {
                System.out.print("Введите номер ячейки: ");
                while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next());
                }
                int numarray = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + numarray + " равна " + array[numarray]);
                System.out.print("Хотите еще раз проверить значение ячеек?: ");
                String accept2 = scan.next();
                if (accept2.equals("Да") || accept2.equals("да") || accept2.equals("дА")) {
                    continue;
                } else if (accept2.equals("Нет") || accept2.equals("нет") || accept2.equals("нЕТ")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю, введите \"Да\" или \"Нет\"");
                }
            }
        } else if (accept.equals("Нет") || accept.equals("нет") || accept.equals("нЕТ") || accept.equals("Стоп") ) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Я Вас не понимаю, введите Да/Нет");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует реализовать отдельные методы для чтения чисел и ответов пользователя "да"/"нет" и вызывать их по мере необходимости.

Также нужно исправить ошибки в логике:

- первая проверка на диапазон номера ячейки выполняется *после* присваивания `array[input] = input2;`
- индекс ячейки, введенный в цикле, вообще не проверяется, поэтому вполне возможны исключения вида `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
- при размере массива в 100 элементов *максимальное допустимое значение индекса* - 99, а не 100 -- следует либо увеличить массив до 101 элемента, либо исправить проверку и сообщения.
- при создании массива целых чисел он заполняется нулями, так что не совсем понятно, для чего вообще нужны два *вложенные* цикла `for`, когда хватило бы одного цикла `do-while`
- для проверки строк независимо от регистра символов следует использовать `String::equalsIgnoreCase` вместо `String::equals`, при этом безопаснее вызывать метод сравнения для константного значения

Исправленный код может выглядеть так:

```java
private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

private static int readInt(String msg) {
    System.out.print(msg);
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next() + ", повторите ввод числа");
    }
    return scan.nextInt();
}

private static int readInt(String msg, int from, int to) {
    int res;
    while ((res = readInt(msg)) < from || res >= to) {
        System.out.printf("Я вас не понимаю, введите число от %d до %d%n", from, to - 1);
    }
    return res;
}

private static boolean readYesNo(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
    do {
        String answer = scan.next();
        if ("да".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            return true;
        } else if ("нет".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю, введите \"Да\" или \"Нет\"");
    } while (true);
}
```

Тогда в методе `main` остаётся существенная логика:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = new int[100];
    
    int index = readInt("Введите номер ячейки: ", 0, array.length);
    int value = readInt("Введите значение, которое будет хранить ячейка: ");
    array[index] = value;
    System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + index + " теперь содержит значение " + value);
    
    if (readYesNo("Хотите проверить, чему равна любая ячейка массива?")) {
        do {
            index = readInt("Введите номер ячейки: ", 0, array.length);
            System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + index + " равна " + array[index]);
        } while (readYesNo("Хотите еще раз проверить значение ячеек?: "));
    }    
}
```

Вариант выполнения:

```
Введите номер ячейки: 1010
Я вас не понимаю, введите число от 0 до 99
Введите номер ячейки: 100
Я вас не понимаю, введите число от 0 до 99
Введите номер ячейки: 99
Введите значение, которое будет хранить ячейка: 1000
Ячейка под номером 99 теперь содержит значение 1000
Хотите проверить, чему равна любая ячейка массива?
no
Я вас не понимаю, введите "Да" или "Нет"
да
Введите номер ячейки: 99
Ячейка под номером 99 равна 1000
Хотите еще раз проверить значение ячеек?: 
да
Введите номер ячейки: 100
Я вас не понимаю, введите число от 0 до 99
Введите номер ячейки: -1
Я вас не понимаю, введите число от 0 до 99
Введите номер ячейки: 25
Ячейка под номером 25 равна 0
Хотите еще раз проверить значение ячеек?: 
не оЯ вас не понимаю, введите "Да" или "Нет"
чнет
Я вас не понимаю, введите "Да" или "Нет"
нет
```

Comment: Вы лучший, спасибо 

Answer (score 1):

Здесь проблема не с циклом , здесь проблема с кодом в целом. Запредельная вложенность, дублирование итд по списку сделали код нечитаемым и разобраться в нем уже на этом этапе, мягко говоря, сложно. Попробуйте для начала делить логику хотя бы на методы (а еще лучше на классы). К примеру, пользовательский ввод сам просится в отдельный метод, ведь это потенциальный источник ошибок, кроме того, он необходим многократно. Соответственно его можно вынести вместе с валидацией, что сильно разгрузит логику.

В общем попробуйте разобраться для начала с этим, а если возникнут вопросы - задавайте:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Array3 {

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static final int[] array = new int[100];

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Integer cellNumber = input("Введите номер ячейки (от 0 до 99):", Integer::valueOf, cell -> cell >= 0 && cell < 100);
        array[cellNumber] = input("Введите значение, которое будет хранить ячейка: ", Integer::valueOf, null);
        printCellValue(cellNumber);
        String userInput;
        do{
            userInput = input("Хотите проверить, чему равна любая ячейка массива (Да/Нет)?", 
                    String::valueOf, v->"да".equalsIgnoreCase(v) || "нет".equalsIgnoreCase(v));
            if ("да".equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)) 
                printCellValue(input("Введите номер ячейки (от 0 до 99): ", Integer::valueOf, cell -> cell >= 0 && cell < 100));
        }while(!"нет".equalsIgnoreCase(userInput));
    }

    private static void printCellValue(Integer cellNumber) {
        System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + cellNumber + " теперь содержит значение " + array[cellNumber]);
    }

    private static <T> T input(String message, Function<String, T> converter, Predicate<T> validator) {
        System.out.println(message);
        try {
            T result = converter.apply(scanner.nextLine());
            if (validator != null && !validator.test(result)) throw new RuntimeException();
            else return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Некорреткный ввод. Повторите попытку.");
            return input(message, converter, validator);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо Дмитрий, я пока еще учусь, и на этапе уже имеющихся знаний хотел реализовать свою задачу, но в будущем я вернусь к Вашему сообщению, спасибо)