# Ошибка при добавлении цикла For

Tags: java

Ребят, всем привет, у меня возникает ошибка, когда я пытаюсь добавить в цикл for еще один цикл for, а именно java: ';' expected. Прошу вас, воспроизведите этот код в своей IDE, и подскажите, в чём проблема? Код рабочий, именно при добавлении цикла, как я делал это ранее возникает ошибка, и более того, при CTRL+Z до исходного состояния появляется вообще новая ошибка, а именно java: 'else' without 'if'.
Вот рабочий код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[100];
    System.out.print("Введите номер ячейки: ");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next());
    }
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите значение, которое будет хранить ячейка: ");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next());
    }
    int input2 = scan.nextInt();
    array[input] = input2;
    if (input >= 0 && input <= 100) {
        System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + input + " теперь содержит значение " + input2);
    } else if (input >= 100 || input < 0) {
        System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю, введите число от 0 до 100");
    }

    System.out.println("Хотите проверить, чему равна любая ячейка массива?");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        String accept = scan.next();
        if (accept.equals("Да") || accept.equals("да") || accept.equals("дА")) {
            for (int itwo = 0; itwo < 10; itwo++) {
                System.out.print("Введите номер ячейки: ");
                while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next());
                }
                int numarray = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + numarray + " равна " + array[numarray]);
                System.out.print("Хотите еще раз проверить значение ячеек?: ");
                String accept2 = scan.next();
                if (accept2.equals("Да") || accept2.equals("да") || accept2.equals("дА")) {
                    continue;
                } else if (accept2.equals("Нет") || accept2.equals("нет") || accept2.equals("нЕТ")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю, введите \"Да\" или \"Нет\"");
                }
            }
        } else if (accept.equals("Нет") || accept.equals("нет") || accept.equals("нЕТ") || accept.equals("Стоп") ) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Я Вас не понимаю, введите Да/Нет");
        }
    }

}

}
```

А вот что я пытаюсь добавить, а именно самый последний else if:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[100];
    System.out.print("Введите номер ячейки: ");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next());
    }
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите значение, которое будет хранить ячейка: ");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next());
    }
    int input2 = scan.nextInt();
    array[input] = input2;
    if (input >= 0 && input <= 100) {
        System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + input + " теперь содержит значение " + input2);
    } else if (input >= 100 || input < 0) {
        System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю, введите число от 0 до 100");
    }

    System.out.println("Хотите проверить, чему равна любая ячейка массива?");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        String accept = scan.next();
        if (accept.equals("Да") || accept.equals("да") || accept.equals("дА")) {
            for (int itwo = 0; itwo < 10; itwo++) {
                System.out.print("Введите номер ячейки: ");
                while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("Ошибка ввода: " + scan.next());
                }
                int numarray = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Ячейка под номером " + numarray + " равна " + array[numarray]);
                System.out.print("Хотите еще раз проверить значение ячеек?: ");
                String accept2 = scan.next();
                if (accept2.equals("Да") || accept2.equals("да") || accept2.equals("дА")) {
                    continue;
                } else if (accept2.equals("Нет") || accept2.equals("нет") || accept2.equals("нЕТ")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Я вас не понимаю, введите \"Да\" или \"Нет\"");
                }
            }
        } else if (accept.equals("Нет") || accept.equals("нет") || accept.equals("нЕТ") || accept.equals("Стоп") ) {
            break;
        } else {
            for(int i3 = 0, i3 < 10, i3++) {
                System.out.println("Я Вас не понимаю, введите Да/Нет");
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: В последнем цикле, у тебя вместо for(int i3=0; i3<10;i3++) стоят запятые, поменяй на ';'

Comment: А какой смысл этого последнего цикла? Выводить 10 раз `Я Вас не понимаю`?  И вроде бы в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1462140/386633) на [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1462107) многие проблемы были разрешены

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделитель не тот использовал, вместо запятой нужна точка с запятой (;)

А вообще, если пишешь в той же Intelij IDEA например, то можно написать fori, нажать Enter и он тебе этот цикл сам сгенерит, останется только указать количество повторений.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но лучше как я понимаю писать такие вещи самому, дабы набивать руку и знать наизусть, и не соблюдать таких ошибок как я)

Comment: да, безусловно, на начальных этапах руку лучше набивать.

Answer (score 1):

В последнем цикле у вас стоят запятые, а нужны точки с запятыми

```
for(int i3 = 0, i3 < 10, i3++)
// а надо 
for(int i3 = 0; i3 < 10; i3++)
```

Comment: Жесть..........